# 2 projects 1 solution- sharing classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to windows mobile development and also Visual Studio.

I am developing a web service as well as a mobile application. I have the 1 solution, but 2 different projects.

I have created a class in the web service (say project 1), but want to be able to use this class in the mobile application (say project 2).

Do I have to basically create a copy of it and reference it in the other project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Create a third project to contain the shared class and add it as a reference in the other two.
2. Keep the class in a single file, but add it to each project as a link, as explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234).

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not need to create copy. Instead, add a reference to `project1` in the `project2`.

Right-click [References->Add Reference...] in `project2`, pick the "Projects" tab, select `project1`, and click [OK].

Answer (score 1):

make your common class as a class library and save it in the form of .dll

whenever you require that class just add its reference to your project and use it  :)

This is called re-use one of the best feature of OOPS

Answer (score 0):

it defeats the purpose of SOA... It becomes Tightly coupled project. One should not add.. Two different layers.. "add as a reference".